# Access a react component method in another component

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

I have two independent react components. One component is used as a central component which will have all the code of API call and database operations. It will have redux store implementation.

so other components need to call the method of the central component to set or get the data. 
Ex: A method in the central component is called from 5 component with different data.

So my question is how can I call the method of this central components? Is there any way to directly access methods from one component to another component with the required data?

Note: It is not having any parent-child relationship between components

Comment: Best practice here is implementing `redux` and use `action`/`reducer` functionallity.

Comment: @kiarashws: So in every component i define an action to send the data from that component to central component or reducer state. So all the component will have same action/reducer to send and receive the data?  I want a simple call instead of handling this in every component.

Comment: see instructions at https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Comment: Why is there no parent-child relationships between components?(At least between the data provider and the presentation) If components use the same data/API calls, then the component making those calls can be a wrapper(container) component. In this case, you can use that same wrapper component on components from different trees.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which version of React you are using. The latest (^16.3.0) provide context api https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html in other way you have to use some state manager like Redux, Mobx.